# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined with owl carousel

Tags: jquery, wordpress, owl-carousel, referenceerror

So i am trying to get Owl Carousel to work properly and I am having no luck. 
I see it is throwing some JQuery errors and am wondering if any of you with more experience with JQuery would know what is going on. 
Here is a link to the page.

[Div Site](http://www.cloudpointtech.com/x123/)

Here is my Owl Carousel HTML set up.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
 
      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
 
      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
 
  });
</script>
```

```css
#owl-demo .item{
  margin: 3px;
}
#owl-demo .item img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- BEGIN PARTNERS SECTION--> 
        <div id="partners_section" class="clearfix">
            <div id="partners_container" class="clearfix">
                <p id="Our_Partners_In_The_Workforce" class="image wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration=".5s" data-wow-delay=".3s"/>
                Our Partners In The Workforce
                </p>

<div id="owl-demo">


 <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 293px;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/" alt="Owl Image"></div>

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
 
      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
 
      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
 
  });
</script>
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- END PARTNERS SECTION-->
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction on what to do to find a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not including the jQuery lib correctly.

jQuery first then plugins

Add above other scripts in the head section:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:** 
You have a DIV in your HEAD tag. Moreover, it is unclosed.

See Here:
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cloudpointtech.com%2Fx123%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks both of you, that fixed most of my issue, but there seems to be one more error throwing. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. It's on line 1.

Comment: Thanks Red. Can't figure out where those "home blog stagtools" errors coming from. Guessing a wordpress plugin, but this is getting me on my way. thanks a lot!

Comment: NP :) Please mark as answer if it answered your initial question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include jquery js file first, and then include owl.carousel.min.js second.